# I'm trying to delete a child element, but I keep getting the error node not found

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to coding so I'm not sure if you get the whole picture with this much, but I can clarify more if this isn't sufficient. Greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
 //remove and complete svg format
 var removeSVG = '<svg></svg>';
 var completeSVG = '<svg></svg>';


 //user clicked on the add button
 //If there is any text in the input field add that to the Todo list
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function () {
var value = document.getElementById('item').value;
if (value) {
    addItemTodo(value);
    document.getElementById('item').value = "";
}

});

function deleteItem() {
var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parent = this.parentNode;

parent.removeChild(item);
}

function completeItem() {
var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parent = this.parentNode;
var id = parent.id;

var target = (id === 'todo') ? document.getElementById('completed') : document.getElementById('todo');

parent.removeChild(item);
target.insertBefore(item, target.childNodes[0]);
}


//Adds a new item to the todo list
function addItemTodo(text) {

var list = document.getElementById('todo');

var item = document.createElement('li');
item.innerText = text;

var buttons = document.createElement('div');
buttons.classList.add('buttons');

var remove = document.createElement('button');
remove.classList.add('remove');
remove.innerHTML = removeSVG;

//add click event for remove button
remove.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);

var complete = document.createElement('button');
complete.classList.add('complete');
complete.innerHTML = completeSVG;

//add click event for the complete button
complete.addEventListener('click', completeItem);

buttons.appendChild(remove);
buttons.appendChild(complete);
item.appendChild(buttons);
list.insertBefore(item, list.childNodes[0]);

}

  //add click event for remove button
remove.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
```

So I posted the whole javascript, so you get an idea of the structure, The html itself is just two  tags with id=todo and completed respectively

Comment: swap the item and parent declaration and you are almost there. this will refer to window. so passing the event object and getting the element with event.target will help you

Comment: post whole code with HTML

Comment: please add the data structure, at least how the nodes are created.

Comment: try giving `item.removeChild(parent);` instead of `parent.removeChild(item);`

Comment: @eltonkamami swapping the declarations removes the button itself!

Comment: Added the whole javascript here

Comment: @AswinRamesh that doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this https://jsfiddle.net/dp722j27/

```
function deleteItem() {
    var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(item);
}
```

Comment: yes you missed one parentNode, also the parent ad the item should be in reverse like `item.removeChild(parent);` instead of `parent.removeChild(item);`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. Could you explain the correction a bit, if you have time?

Comment: yes.. one point is you missed one parentNode, the other one is, In your code, the `item = this.parentNode.parentNode` and `var parent = this.parentNode` and the remove statement is `parent.removeChild(item)` so it means you are trying to remove the child `item` of `parent`. but your variable declaration seems to be opposite `item` is the parent element of variable `parent`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete button, that was clicked, do like this:

```
function deleteItem(event) {
  var item = event.target.parentNode;
  var parent = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(item);
}

  //add click event for remove button
document.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
```